# Node mdns dns service error

Tags: node.js, dns, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mdns

I'm trying to implement zeroconf protocole with mdns node module but when I use it I have this error (on raspberry pi 2) :

```
error: Error: dns service error: unknown
    at Error (native)
    at new Advertisement (/var/www/lisa/node_modules/mdns/lib/advertisement.js:56:10)
    at Object.create [as createAdvertisement] (/var/www/lisa/node_modules/mdns/lib/advertisement.js:64:10)
    at Object.module.exports.bootstrap (/var/www/lisa/config/bootstrap.js:22:17)
    at Sails.runBootstrap (/var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/bootstrap.js:44:25)
    at Sails.bound [as runBootstrap] (/var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at Sails.initialize (/var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/lib/app/private/initialize.js:48:9)
    at bound (/var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/node_modules/lodash/dist/lodash.js:729:21)
    at /var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:607:21
    at /var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:246:17
    at iterate (/var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:146:13)
    at /var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25
    at /var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:248:21
    at /var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:612:34
    at /var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/lib/app/load.js:201:13
    at /var/www/lisa/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:451:17
```

Here is my code :

```
var mdns       = require('mdns');
var txt_record = {
    name     : 'Test module'
};
var ad = mdns.createAdvertisement(mdns.tcp('http'), 4321, txt_record);
ad.start();
```